# How to use structure a bson query with query,where and in using go

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, go-fiber

I would like to get document entries based on time range and  a field that is used in $in. I can do it very easily using mongoose and nodejs like so where param is the key and params is an array

```
Data.find( 
         {
          timestamp:
                 {
          $gte: new Date(query.startDate),
          $lt: new Date(query.endDate)
               }
         }
       ).where(`${param}`).in(params);
```

Below is my attempt with bson using go and bson. I am finding it diffucult on how to structure the query

```
aliases := []string {"000","111"}
query := bson.M{
        "datetime": bson.M{
            "$gt": startDate,
            "$lt": endDate,
        },
     "$where":bson.M{"device_alias":bson.M{"$in": aliases}}
        
    }
```

Kindly could someone help me figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is not a valid mongodb query. Try this instead:

```
query := bson.M{
        "datetime": bson.M{
            "$gt": startDate,
            "$lt": endDate,
        },
        "device_alias":bson.M{"$in": aliases},
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it compiles successfully. So it is not necessary to have the $where operator in this case?

Comment: No, The `$where` operator has a quite different use case: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#mongodb-query-op.-where

Comment: Thank you, from the docs it is a JS thing, so is it safe to say one does not use $where in go ?

Comment: This is related to mongodb not to go